# Value is not passed to Variable(JQuery, Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JQuery-Code like this:

```
    $.post("count_images.php",{}, function(data)
    {
        if (data != '')
        {
            alert(data);
        }
        else
        {
            //Error
        }
    });
```

It simply sends a request to `count_images.php` and returns a number like `23` for example. This works perfectly fine, but when i change it into this:

```
    var number_images;

    $.post("count_images.php",{}, function(data)
    {
        if (data != '')
        {
            number_images = data;
        }
        else
        {
            //Error
        }
    });

    alert(number_images);
```

It does not work correctly. The alert-function always outputs an `undefined`. I simply want to save the result saved in `data` in a variable called `number_images` so i can keep on working with that. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$.post()` method is asynchronous, so when the second code snippet runs, the `alert` will be fired off before the AJAX POST returns with date, hence why `number_images` is `undefined` (as it hasn't been populated yet).

You can have the POST be executed synchronously by using [$.ajax()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) and passing `async: false` and `method: 'POST'` flags. But this is not usually a good idea, as it defeats the entire purpose of AJAX (the A stands for asynchronous, after all).

Alternatively, either use the callback function (same as the first snippet) or attack other callbacks using the [jQuery Promise API](https://api.jquery.com/Types/#Promise). For example

```
    $.post("count_images.php")
    .done(function(data)
    {
        if (data != '')
        {
            alert(data);
        }
        else
        {
            //Error
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that $.post() is an asynchronous method and all that code is in a callback function, so when

```
alert(number_images);
```

is called, your callback function likely has not run yet because $.post() is still waiting for a response.

You need to put anything that uses number_images in the callback. It might be helpful to define another function like so:

```
var number_images;

var do_stuff_with_number_images = function() {
  alert(number_images);
  // any other code referencing number_images goes here
};

$.post("count_images.php",{}, function(data)
{
    if (data != '')
    {
        number_images = data;
    }
    else
    {
        //Error
    }

    do_stuff_with_number_images();
});

alert(number_images);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var number_images,
      data ='';

$.post("count_images.php",{}, function(data)
{
    if (data != '')
    {
        number_images = data;
    }
    else
    {
        //Error
    }
});

alert(number_images);
```